# How to make this closure compiler warning go away?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I'm trying out adv mode and get the following error

> JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: actual parameter 1 of $jscomp.makeIterator does not match formal parameter
>   found   : Input_0$classdecl$var0
>   required: (Arguments|Array|Iterable|Iterator|string) at line x character Y
>       // @output_file_name default.js
>         for (let [name] of this)

The class looks something like this (largely simplified)

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name default.js
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// ==/ClosureCompiler==

module.exports = class {
  *entries() {
    yield 'bob'
  }

  *values() {
    for (let name of this)
      yield name
  }

  [Symbol.iterator]() {
    return this.entries()
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the closure? why not just `module.exports = class{...}`?

Comment: I had more code around inside of it. Apparently I didn't strip it enough...